# Shibboleth variables not coming over with Coldfusion 2021 & IIS

Tags: azure-active-directory, coldfusion, shibboleth, shibboleth-sp

I am trying to use Shibboleth 3 as the sp and azure AD as the ipd and I can see that I have successfully implemented based on the Shibboleth transaction log.

> 2022-12-16 12:35:54|Shibboleth-TRANSACTION.AuthnRequest|||https://sts.windows.net/c04845f0-4224-4637-aed2-9beea8319b5b/||||||urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect||||||
>
> 2022-12-16 12:35:55|Shibboleth-TRANSACTION.Login||_292e2cf9f81890bcdf7ffe1cd147c92f|https://sts.windows.net/c04845f0-4224-4637-aed2-9beea8319b5b/|_ff1422a3-4c91-4255-adec-fa6fd52d2600|urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password|2022-12-16T07:00:19|authnmethodsreferences(2),displayname(1),emailaddress(1),givenname(1),groups(1),identityprovider(1),objectidentifier(1),surname(1),tenantid(1)|davisg1@XXXXX.com|urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST||urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success|||Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/108.0.1462.46|167.244.201.154

I changed the email in the text above to "davisg1@XXXXX.com" for obvious reasons.

However I can't seem to retrieve the variables on my Coldfusion page.  I have googled endlessly and not found an answer.

I tried dumping cgi and getHTTPRequestData() and i also tried hardcoding like http_givenName #cgi['http_givenName']# and HTTP_REMOTE_USER  #cgi['HTTP_REMOTE_USER']# but nothing useful appears

I have updated by attributes-map.xml to use the "name" field returned by azure AD and made sure that in shibboleth.xml that ApplicationDefaults REMOTE_USER uses persistentID

```
<Attribute name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" id="persistent-id">   <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="NameIDAttributeDecoder" formatter="$NameQualifier!$SPNameQualifier!$Name" defaultQualifiers="true"/>
</Attribute> 

<ApplicationDefaults entityID="https://intranettest.amc.edu/shibboleth-sp"
    REMOTE_USER="eppn subject-id pairwise-id persistent-id"
    cipherSuites="DEFAULT:!EXP:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL:!DES:!IDEA:!SEED:!RC4:!3DES:!kRSA:!SSLv2:!SSLv3:!TLSv1:!TLSv1.1">
```

Comment: I was able to get cgi.auth_user and cgi.remote_user populated after changing the code in attributes-map.xml to <Attribute name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" id="NameID">
       <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="StringAttributeDecoder" caseSensitive="false"/>
    </Attribute> and then in shibboleth.xml adding NameID to ApplicationDefaults but none of the other vars sent over by azure ad are populated

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to add  useHeaders="true" to the ISAPI tag in shibboleth2.xml

```
 <ISAPI normalizeRequest="true" safeHeaderNames="true" useHeaders="true">
```